# Has anybody implemented WSO2 to AKS integration (microservices in AKS)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, azure-aks, wso2-cloud

There is a lag introduced between the WSO2 and the microservice layer running on AKS. Tried to tweak every single parameter recommended by WSO2 but there are slight improvements only. Can anyone help?

Comment: what's your APIM version?

Comment: APIM version - WSO2 2.6.0

Comment: You can use the observability feature to narrow down the issue. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Observability

Comment: Will do and check. In the meantime, can you please let us know if http pass through has a better performance compared to nhttp?

Comment: Yes, it has ...